# Flash getURL() not working from inside movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I recently face a problem that my code working from root but when i put this movie clip inside movie clip its not working

```
on(release){
getURL("fast_facts.html")
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.getURL("fast_facts.html", "_blank", "GET");

Comment: also have a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001307.html

Comment: or this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001307.html   you may have to add a listener

Comment: try _root.getURL and also switch the properties to Track as MenuItem

Comment: sample file link

http://escribir.biz/nb1/sample.fla

http://escribir.biz/nb1/sample.swf

the main box have on rollover and on rollout effect and link is in this movie clip on layer 2 and box in layer 1 in actual movie there are many boxes like this which have links but when rollover work link on release not work

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: your file is corrupt won't open for me. can open the swf alright. email the fla to me rachelgallen@gmail.com i won't me able to look it for another 4 hours or so so i'll mail it back to you then if i get it working.

Comment: worth a go! i promise i'll have a look

Comment: its made on flash cs5 maybe thats why its not opening

Comment: i can download cs5 that's not a problem

Comment: what is the full url of fastfacts.html?/

Comment: sent you a mail - check it